# Weighted Sum Based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose you have this dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "id" : [1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4],
    "weight" : [0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.25, 0.25, 0.10, 0.40],
    "val" : [55, 325, 532, 55, 29, 89, 38, 85]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

id  weight  val
1   0.5     55
1   0.5     325
2   1       532
3   1       55
4   0.25    29
4   0.25    89
4   0.10    38
4   0.40    85
```

I.e. we have id columns, weights that sum to 1 for each id "group", and a value column.

I want to create a weighted sum of each val column for each id group.

So for id 1 it would be:

```
0.5 * 55 + 0.5 * 325 = 190
```

Etc.

It should return a new series with this result with unique IDs and weighted values.

I tried something like

```
df.groupby("id").apply(lambda (x["val"] * x["weight"]).sum())
```

but it's not really correct.

Appreciate all help!

Comment: Check for typo in your lambda function: `df.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: (x["val"] * x["weight"]).sum())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @mosc9575's answer, you could avoid `apply` and hopefully get better performance by first computing the individual values (weight multiplied by val) before getting the sums per group:

```
df.assign(weighted_sum=df.weight.mul(df.val).groupby(df.id).transform("sum"))

    id  weight  val weighted_sum
0   1   0.50    55  190.0
1   1   0.50    325 190.0
2   2   1.00    532 532.0
3   3   1.00    55  55.0
4   4   0.25    29  67.3
5   4   0.25    89  67.3
6   4   0.10    38  67.3
7   4   0.40    85  67.3
```